# Making crossoff(Strikethrough) in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm start learning Reactjs, and i try to made my first app (To-do-List), i want help in how to make Strike-through on the completed task when i click the button

```
//index.js
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import loading from './loading.gif'
import './App.css';
import ListItem from './listItem';

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  newTodo: '',
  isEmpty: false,
  editing: false,
  editingIndex: null,
  nofication :null,
  notifyFlag : false,
  notifyEditFlag :false,
  loading : true,
  finish : false,
  todos: []
 };
  this.apiUrl = 'https://5d87dcecfeddff0014e1568d.mockapi.io'
  this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this);
  this.updateTodo = this.updateTodo.bind(this);
  this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  // this.generateTodoId = this.generateTodoId.bind(this);
  this.displayNofication = this.displayNofication.bind(this);
  this.doneTodo = this.doneTodo.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}/todos`);
  setTimeout(()=>{
  this.setState({
  todos: response.data,
  loading : false
  });
  },1000)
  }

 async doneTodo(item, index){
 console.log(item.name.strike());
 const todo = this.state.todos[index];
 const response = await axios.put(`${this.apiUrl}/todos/${todo.id}`,{ 
 })
 this.setState({
  finish : true,
 })

 }

 handleChange(event) {
 this.setState({
  newTodo: event.target.value
  });
  if (/^[\s]*([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\s]*)*$/.test(event.target.value)) {
  this.setState({
      isEmpty : true
  })
  } else {
  this.setState({
    isEmpty : false
   })
   }
  }

  // generateTodoId() {
  //   const lastTodo = this.state.todos[this.state.todos.length - 1];
  //   if (lastTodo) {
  //     return lastTodo.id + 1;
  //   }

  //   return 1;
  // }

  async addTodo() {
  if(this.state.isEmpty){
// const newTodo = {
//   name: this.state.newTodo,
//   id: this.generateTodoId()
// };

const response = await axios.post(`${this.apiUrl}/todos`, {
  name: this.state.newTodo
});


const todos = this.state.todos;
todos.push(response.data);

this.setState({
  todos: todos,
  newTodo: '',
  isEmpty :false,
  nofication:this.displayNofication(),
  notifyFlag:true
  });
  this.displayNofication("todo added successfuly")
  }
  }

  editTodo(index) {
  const todo = this.state.todos[index];
  this.setState({
  editing: true,
  newTodo: todo.name,
  editingIndex: index,
  notifyEditFlag :true,
  });
  }

  async updateTodo() {
   this.setState({
  loading : true
   })
   const todo = this.state.todos[this.state.editingIndex];

  const response = await axios.put(`${this.apiUrl}/todos/${todo.id}`,{
  name : this.state.newTodo
  })

  // todo.name = this.state.newTodo;

  const todos = this.state.todos;
  todos[this.state.editingIndex] = response.data;
  setTimeout(()=>{
  this.setState({
  todos,
  editing: false,
  editingIndex: null,
  newTodo: '',
  loading : false
   });
  },1000)
  this.displayNofication("todo update successfuly");
  }

  async deleteTodo(index) {
 const todos = this.state.todos;
 const todo = todos[index]
 await axios.delete(`${this.apiUrl}/todos/${todo.id}`)
 delete todos[index];
 this.setState({ 
  todos,
  notifyFlag:false
 });
 this.displayNofication("todo deleted successfuly")
 }

 displayNofication(notify){
 this.setState({
  nofication :notify
  })
 setTimeout(()=>{
  this.setState({
    nofication : null,
    notifyEditFlag:false
  });
   }, 2000)

  }

  render() {
   return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h1 className="App-title">CRUD React</h1>
    </header>
    <div className="container">
      {
       this.state.notifyEditFlag ? this.state.nofication&&<div className="alert mt-3 alert-info"><p>{this.state.nofication}</p></div>:this.state.notifyFlag ? this.state.nofication&&<div className="alert mt-3 alert-success"><p>{this.state.nofication}</p></div>:this.state.nofication&&<div className="alert mt-3 alert-danger"><p>{this.state.nofication}</p></div>
      }
      <input
        type="text"
        name="todo"
        className="my-4 form-control"
        placeholder="Add a new todo"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.newTodo}
      />
      <button
        onClick={this.state.editing ? this.updateTodo : this.addTodo}
        className="btn-info mb-3 form-control">
        {this.state.editing ? 'Update todo' : 'Add todo'}
      </button>
      {
        this.state.loading&& <img src={loading} alt="loading Gif"/>
      }
      {
        !this.state.editing &&
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.state.todos.map((item, index) => {
            return <ListItem  
            key={item.id}
            item={item}
            finish={this.state.finish}
            editTodo={()=>{this.editTodo(index);}}
            deleteTodo={()=>{this.deleteTodo(index);}}
            doneTodo={()=>{this.doneTodo(index);}} 
            />
     })}
        </ul>
      }
    </div>
  </div>
  );
   }
   }

  export default App;
```

listItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

 const ListItem = (props) => {
 return <li className="list-group-item">

<button
  className="btn-sm mr-4 btn btn-info"
  onClick={props.editTodo}
>U</button>
{props.finish ?  <strike>{props.item.name}</strike>: `${props.item.name}`}
<button
  className="btn-sm ml-4 btn btn-danger"
  onClick={props.deleteTodo}
>X</button>
<button className="btn-sm ml-4 btn btn-info" onClick={props.doneTodo}>Done!</button>
 </li>;
      };

  export default ListItem;
```

when i clicked button Done! it make all tasks as completed, i only need specific index (li)tag that i clicked the button done in, so you any one could help me to handel it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is,

> 1. Storing the state of a ToDo in `finish` flag.
> 2. When a ToDo is marked 'Done', you're updating the `finish` flag.

Points to keep in mind -

1. For a React component, whenever the `prop` or `state` changes, the component will re-render.
2. You can't store state of n ToDo items in a single boolean flag `finish`.

This is what's happening in your code:

> 1. You click on Done for any ToDo item.
> 2. Control goes to `doneTodo` and an axios PUT call is made.
> 3. After that, state variable `finish` is updated.
> 4. Since state is updated, your `App` component renders again.
> 5. During the render, for every `ListItem`, a `finish` value of true is passed from state.
> 6. So every ToDo item, is rendered as Done.

To fix the issue, you could choose to have a state `finishStatus` as array (similar to `todos`), and update the array index when a Done is clicked (Also need to pass respective value to `finish` prop of `ListItem`.

Something like this - https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-basic-todo-stack-58086171-xkt5t